# ETH multisig wallet with Trezor integration

Tags: wallets, hardware-wallets

advice would be appreciated! I am looking for a reliable Ether wallet with two features: 
*Multisig 
*Integration with any hardware wallets (Trezor would be more preferable option)

It seems that Mist supports multisig, but does not any hardware wallet. Moreover, it is necessaty to download the whole blockchain on my computer. What about more light version? I heard about ConsenSys, but it seems that it is currently in the testing period. How safe is it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gnosis multisig desktop application supports Trezor and Ledger hardware wallets.

It is available for Mac, Windows and Linux.

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/releases

Comment: As far as I understood, there is no way to use Trezor with Parity. Right?

Comment: This answer was. Updated.